# How do I make different buttons in css?

Tags: html, css

So right now I have a button and this is what that button looks like right now:

```
input[type=button] {
    background: blue;
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0.5%;
}
```

Now let's say I want three more buttons. They all look the same except in addition to my blue button one is red, another is yellow, and the fourth button is green. How do I go about creating these new buttons in css?

Comment: Use CSS classes and then reference them like `input.button_blue`, `input.button_red`, `input.button_yellow`, `input.button_green`

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, I think this is a great question about good practice which highlights the heart of what a 'class' is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
input[type=button] {
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0.5%;
}
.red{
  background-color: red;
}
.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="red"/>

<input type="button" class="blue"/>

<input type="button" class="yellow"/>
```

Try to use `class`

Answer (score 2):

you can define color classes and put it into your button class property.

```
input[type=button] {
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0.5%;
}
.blue{
    background: blue;
}
.red{
    background: red;
}
.yellow{
    background: yellow;
}
.green{
    background: green;
}
```

HTML :

```
<input type="button" class="red" value="Red button">
<input type="button" class="blue" value="Blue button">
<input type="button" class="green" value="Green button">
<input type="button" class="yellow" value="Yellow button">
```

Answer (score 1):

ok dear you have different methods

1 st one

```css
input[type=button]
  {
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0.5%;
  }
  .blue 
  {
   background-color: blue;
  }
  .red
  {
   background-color: red;

  }
  .yellow
  {
   background-color: yellow;
  }
  .green
  {
   background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
  <input class="blue" type="button" name="">
 <input class="red" type="button" name="">
 <input class="yellow" type="button" name="">
 <input class="green" type="button" name="">
```

2nd one

```css
input[type=button]
  {
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0.5%;
  }
```

```html
  <input  type="button" name="" style="background-color: green;">
 <input  type="button" name="" style="background-color: blue;">
 <input  type="button" name="" style="background-color: yellow;">
 <input  type="button" name="" style="background-color: red;">
```